# free(): invalid pointer Aborted (core dumped) at fclose();

Tags: c, file, fclose

I am trying to call this function two times and when I call it for the second time it gives me this error after printing the row and clm

```
void datasize(char fl_name[], int* rw, int* clm)
{
    FILE* fl;

    fl = fopen(fl_name, "r+");
    char fldata[100];
    int i = 0, il;
    int j = 0, jl = 0;

    if (fl==NULL)
    {
        printf("%s doesnot exists in the current folder (folder of the executable)\n",fl_name);
    }
    while (fgets(fldata, 100, fl))
    {
        if (fldata[0] > 47 && fldata[0] < 60)
        {
            j = 0;
            char* tokn = strtok(fldata, ",");
            while (tokn)
            {
                if (((tokn[0] > 47) && (tokn[0] < 60)) || tokn[0] == '-')
                {
                    j++;
                }
                tokn = strtok(NULL, ",");
            }
            jl = (j > jl) ? j : jl;
            while (j <= jl)
            {
                j++;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
    il = i;
    *rw = il;
    *clm = jl;
    printf("\n");
    printf("row : %d clm : %d", il, jl);
    printf("\n");
    fclose(fl);
}
```

output:

```
Reading Line Data.....
row : 20 clm : 7
Done
Reading Bus Data.....
row : 14 clm : 9
free(): invalid pointer
Aborted (core dumped)
```

The part between Reading Data and Done has the function call. We can see that it prints the row and clm but it gives this error at fclose();

I would really appreciate if anyone guide me to the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: I guess you need to add a `return;` statement in your `if (f1 == NULL) { ...` block. Otherwise, you ending up calling `fclose` on that `NULL` pointer.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have just tried that it is giving the same error again.

Comment: Please provide complete code as a [mre]. That is provide the `main` and any other code that is needed to reproduce the problem. The root cause may not be in the code shown (e.g. could be a memory corruption somewhere else that triggers here).

Comment: I was using 2 functions and i called fclose on the same pointer in both functions. The issue is resolved now. Thanks.

Comment: Exactly as we guessed - the problem was in code we could not see. Please be sure to post a [mre] next time. Though the explanation you have given doesn't really make sense. The `fl` variable is only accessible in this function so how is it possible to `fclose` it anywhere else? Implies you haven't really found the root cause. Note that bugs like memory corruption can appear to go away when you change unrelated code and then reappear at any time if you have not actually fixed it.

Comment: Please, in order for others to be able to read and correct your code, use meaningful identifiers, as we cannot guess what are those identifiers used for, or what they mean.  And, as it has been requested in other comment, please, post a minimal  and reproducible example. That means a complete compilable & runnable example we can test.  Many times the problem is not in the code you post, but in the one you hide from us.

Comment: Here is the link for minimal reproducible code.
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1oI68Y128NnN4ulR0hpFGJ-uM0s6xGkye?usp=sharing